# In PHP, what is a binary string (b'xxxx')?

Tags: php

What does `b''` ("binary string") mean in the PHP statement `$str=b'xxxxxx';`?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean?

Answer (score -9, accepted):

```
$number = decbin(59);
echo $number . "\n"; //111011
$number = bindec($number);
echo $number . "\n"; //59
```

[decbin(int $number)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php): Returns a string containing a binary representation of the given number argument.

[bindec(string $bstring)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php): Returns the decimal equivalent of the binary number in bstring argument.

Comment: This is answering the wrong question... granted, the question was not well-written, but it pertains to the "binary string" type as used in the `b'xxxx'` syntax in PHP, not to a binary number represented as a text string.

Answer (score 16):

The PHP [language reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-binary.php) describes the distinction between unicode strings and native binary strings, denoted with b'this is a binary string'

It *doesn't* seem to be a method of representing binary numbers.

The notation "is available since PHP 5.2.1. However, it will only have effect as of PHP 6.0.0"

Comment: The source of your answer is actually a user comment in the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/fr/language.types.string.php#93576 This is not too reliable.

Comment: Here's a more authoritative documentation: https://web.archive.org/web/20090403051843/http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-binary.php

Comment: The well known PHP 6.0.0

Answer (score 16):

Binary strings were introduced in PHP 5.2.1 but were expected to become effective only starting from PHP 6. It was an attempt to distinguish between Unicode and binary strings. The former being the new string format, the latter being the current format but changed to "b" notation.

As you may know, PHP 6 had been abandoned and string format didn't change. The "b" notation is just a relic from that era.

```
'foobar' === b'foobar'; // true
```

So nowadays (PHP 5 and 7), binary string is the only string format. The character encoding (which can be multibyte) is managed at the "upper level", by your text editor, web browser, etc. You can consider a binary string to be a string consisting of the full 0-255 range of byte values.

A string with nonprintable characters and such, can be manipulated in PHP as any other string, but you'll get garbage displaying it. Also some characters have special meaning: `\0` marks string termination in C and SQL, there are control characters, etc. So as soon as you use them outside of PHP you are likely to encounter troubles.

For example, [`random_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) produces such strings.

Comment: I encounter trouble with JSON. But PHP randomly returns my string with 'b' and sometimes without. That's why, sometimes my JSON is not rendered and sometimes it is.. It's driving me crazy ! If someone is in this case, it could be useful to know that JSON does not handle this "b"

Comment: Feel free to post a question for your case.

Answer (score 3):

"binary string" is what we have in php right now - a sequence of bytes, which (as opposed to C language) can also include nul byte. This is (or will be, as of php6) different from unicode strings, which are sequences of two-byte characters.