# String with a "b" prefix on records with accent

Tags: php, laravel, encoding

When I dump the property of my model and it has an accent it returns with this "b" prefix

```
dump($venda_item->produto->nomeproduto); // b"teste téste"
```

My database is setted to utf8 and utf8_general_ci collation

This causes me the following error `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` when I'm returning the response in json, at this line

```
$json_response = Response::json($response, $this->getStatusCode(), $headers);
```

## Update

I discovered that if I die and dump the record on the web route it shows normal `teste téste`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    dd(App\Vendasitem::where('codigovi', 112685)->first()->produto->nomeproduto);
}
```

otherwise if I do the same in the controller or request and other files that I tryied it keeps returning me with the "b" prefix

## Update 2

If I save my record like this `PROMO - VIRICAPS (GUARANÃ¡ + POLIVIT) 60 CÃ¡PS - CAIXA 18 UND` and `dump($venda_item->produto->nomeproduto);` it returns me the right result with the accents.

All my database, including the column is set up to `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: Why is it with a prefix b, it broks my json, gives me a malformed utf8

Comment: Given the way your data was corrupted when you tried @jfreites's non-answer it looks like you're still getting the data in a single-byte encoding. You should double-check that you're setting the correct charset when you set up your DB connection. Also, mysql tends to not care if you put not-UTF8 into a table with UTF8 as the declared encoding and will give you that nonsense straight back. Check your source data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Sammitch I can't figure out, in laravel, my database settings is http://prntscr.com/mkoqaw using Navicat I see that my table is with the same following configuration http://prntscr.com/mkoqti same with the current table http://prntscr.com/mkor23 and I alredy update the field manually to fix any copy and paste with incorrect encoding, what else do I need to check?

Comment: @Sammitch another print of the database http://prntscr.com/mkorst

Comment: For reference: `b'...'` are binary strings, introduced in [5.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20090403051843/http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-binary.php) but deprecated by PHP 7. That they cause problems with JSON [is known](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273464/2908724). There's no actual question in your post, that I can see. Can you clarify what you're wanting to know?

Comment: @bishop the string shouldn't be a binary string, thats the problem, it is just a string with an accent, I want to know wat is causing it to become a binary string, debuging laravels framkework, i've notice that it becomes a binary string in some part between a pipeline and the authentication middleware how you can see in my another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708267/getting-binary-data-after-pipeline

Comment: @bishop I'm using PHP 7 so this string shouldn't show up right?

Comment: What type has this `nomeproduto` column?

Comment: @Styx varchar(255)

Comment: Show also your `Vendasitem` model, please.

Comment: Are you sure that the column has the same collation as the table? You can check it with request like SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM produto WHERE Field = 'nomeproduto'

Comment: @AndriiFilenko Yes, I've alredy checked that too http://prntscr.com/mmuq2r

Comment: Your second update is somewhat messed up at the end.

Comment: @Styx this hole problem is a mess kkk but I simplified, take a look

Comment: Yes, it is. I was sure your DB had `utf8mb4` from the start, seems like I've read the question inattentively :) You shouldn't have problems with `utf8mb4` in future.

Comment: @Styx before it was only in `utf8`, but I still with problem, cause in my database it should be with the correct caracter not that weird one

Comment: The problem was using `utf8` encoding for database. It isn't _real_ unicode actually. `utf8mb4` however, is.

Comment: Did you try `utf8_encode($venda_item->produto->nomeproduto)` before transforming to json?

Comment: @GlaucoA.Amigo that inverts my error on web route it will show the wrong string and in the controllers it will be okay, I have more pages that I show that same field and I can't convert every field that I have cause it is hundreds

Comment: @SpaceDogCS Hold on, are still having this problem?

Comment: @Styx Yes if I put an accent on the database, it still returning binary, if I use this encode `Ã¡` that I don't know the name, it shows the accent normal

Comment: @SpaceDogCS How do you "put an accent into database"? Though usual methods in your code?

Comment: @Styx I've made severals projects with accents, never changing anything on my configuration, here you can see an example http://prntscr.com/moq5ev I just save the value of an html form input, but if I open my table and manualy put an phrase with accent works too

Comment: @Styx always in utf8 and utf8_general_ci

Comment: @SpaceDogCS Your answers are confusing. You should have `utf8mb4` always and there won't be such problems.

Comment: @Styx yes, but in all my projects I always have utf8 and never had this problem, now in this project I have this problem with both utf8 and utf8mb4

Answer (score 3):

If you already confirmed the encoding on your database. Have a look on `config/database.php`, on charset and collation proprieties.

```php
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

If the issue is on the "print" then you might use the `utf8_encode` function.

```php
{{utf8_encode($yourVar)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when importing data from a different database. Solved with this method, maybe it works for you to.

```
public function fixEncoding($str) {
        return mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8') 
                ? html_entity_decode($str) 
                : utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($str));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, it looks like your best bet is to [write a accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for the object using [iconv](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
public function getNomeprodutoAttribute($value) {
   return iconv("utf-8", "utf-8//ignore", $value);
}
```

Unless you want to recode the whole database, which probably isn't an option.

The value passed in will the value out of the database (which is the unfortunate binary data).  Then you are telling it the input is utf (which it is), and that the output is utf8 (which we want) but to ignore chars that aren't supported in utf-8.  `//ignore` may work in some versions of the library, so you'd just have to do the following, and hope for the best:

```
public function getNomeprodutoAttribute($value) {
   return iconv("utf-8", "utf-8", $value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but, two problens, first, I'll need to do this to every column that I have, second it gives me an error `iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`

Answer (score -2):

Use this function

```
public function utf8ize($value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                $value[$k] = utf8ize($v);
            }
        } else if (is_string ($value)) {
            return utf8_encode($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does?

Comment: please check this - https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/utf8ize/php-utf8ize-function-examples.html

Comment: if sting is not UTF-8 format then we have to encode using `utf8_encode()`

Comment: @cbaconnier do u know the answer ? if know post your answer

Comment: I do not have an answer. My assumptions is that @SpaceDogCS mixed encoding between Laravel and the database. (IIRC file encoding is also a thing on Windows)